# geometric progression point distribution when one extreme point is negetive

Tags: linear-algebra, geometric-progressions

How to generate 20 points from -0.01 to 100 which are geometrically equal in separation means if I want to plot in log scale  $\log d_2 - \log d_1  = \log d_3 - \log d_2$  where $d_1$, $d_2$, $d_3$ are some points in between them. I can generate 20  points from 0.01 to 100 which follow a geometrical progression. However, if the extreme boundary is negative what is the procedure.

Comment: Would you be alright with a partition of $[a,b]=[-0.01,100]$ in which it was the *lengths* of the subintervals which were in geometric progression? I mean rather than the subinterval endpoints. If so it wouldn't matter if it happened that $a<0,\ b>0$ because the subinterval lengths would all be positive anyway.

Comment: @coffeemath Yes that is true $[a, b] = [-0.01, 100]$ the leangth of subinterval in geometric progression. My point is when the transition from negetive to possitive how it can be expressed

Comment: In your post it looks like you're looking at the logs of the division points. But you can instead look at the logs of the lengths. By the way if constant lengths are used, it is technically a geometric progression with common ratio $1.$ Are you trying to avoid that case? What specifically do you want to hold about the common ratio which would exclude all equal lengths? Also for calculation one needs to know how many intervals in the partition.

Comment: Sudhir--- Please see my answer below and let me know your reactions. Thanks. A somewhat interesting question which took me a while to get a workable answer to. [So +1 on question,]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to partition an interval $[a,b]$ into  $m$ subintervals whose lengths form a geometric progression. Use the formula
$$g(k)=2a-b+2^{k/m}\cdot(b-a) \tag{1}$$
for $k=0,1,\cdots m$ to give the $m+1$ endpoints of the partition. Then the *lengths* of the $m$ subintervals are (for $k$ from $1$ to $m$) given by $g(k)-g(k-1).$ The common ratio of the geometric progression of lengths is $2^{1/m}.$

I did this for your case of $[a,b]=[-0.01,100]$ using $m=12$ intervals and it worked fine. [I realize you wanted $20$ intervals but you can re-do this for that choice.] Here we have
$$g(k)=-100.02+2^{k/12}\cdot(100.01). \tag{2}$$
To check the ratio one needs two adjacent intervals, so three successive values of $g(k).$ The first three $g(k)$ [to 4 decimals] are $-0.01,5.9369,12.2374.$ This gives the first *two* lengths as $5.9469,\ 6.3005$ and the ratio between these is $6.3005/5.9469=1.0594..$ which is the same as $2^{1/12}$ to four places. I checked also a few more cases of adjacent intervals, which I invite you to do also. I also checked that the last division point $g(12)$ is $100.0$ as expected.

There are likely a lot of other ways to interpose the points, but this method definitely is not sensitive to the possibility that the interval $[a,b]$ has $0$ in its interior and so some division points are negative and others positive.

NOTE: If anyone read this already I had left out a $2$ in the main formula (1). Now fixed.